# Load external SVG file into variable and append to html

Tags: jquery, svg

I'm trying to replace an SVG image embedded in IMG tag with the content of this SVG and output it inline. In other words lo load the contents of SVG file of given IMG SRC attribute into a variable and inject it as inline SVG into HTML, like this:

...

```
else if (type && type === 'img-simple') {
    if (format === 'svg' ) {
         $.get(src, function(data) {
         var svg = $(data);
         $bg.append(svg);
    });
```

} else {

...

Where var type is image class and format is the image type: jpg, sag etc.

Which gives me the following error:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (img01.svg, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/img01.svg. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (index.html, line 0)
```

Apparently it's the get function problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there any other way to load the contents of an sag file into jQuery variable (in order to append it to html)?

Comment: Is it possible that the svg file is not on your server?

Comment: I'm testing it from local folder (not server version) ...

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't see that src is probably "file:///Users/img01.svg". This won't work. Also, do you have a webserver running?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot load data via ajax using the `file://` protocol. You need to use `http://`

For example, move the svg file to the same folder as your javascript file and then do:

```
$.get('img01.svg', function(data) {
    $bg.append(data);
});
```