# How to load SVG file contents with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, get

I am trying to access the contents of an SVG file using jQuery AJAX but keep getting the same error in Chrome.

#### JavaScript

```
$.get("my.svg", function(data){
  print(data)
})
```

#### Console Output

```
[Error] jquery.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:'///Users/james.jensen/Desktop/helloworld/my.svg'. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

I literally copied and pasted the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286486/load-external-svg-file-into-variable-and-append-to-html) and changed it to fit my situation, so I am unsure why my code is malfunctioning in this way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it has to be an http call. You cannot load files/data via ajax using file:// protocol.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery appending to AJAX loaded SVG problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802283/jquery-appending-to-ajax-loaded-svg-problem)

Comment: @abhishekkhandait The HTML file that runs the above JavaScript is in the same folder as the `my.svg`, so as you can see I used `$.get("my.svg"...)`. I believe that acts as an HTTP call?

Comment: try adding a "/" to the url. 
`$.get("/my.svg"...)`

Comment: @abhishekkhandait I already tried that. Chrome treats the URL as `file:///my.svg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this issue is, in fact, Chrome related. I ran the same code on Safari and it worked perfectly. I looked into solutions that would enable me to run the same code on Chrome and discovered that I would have to run a server locally.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.get('/my.svg', function(svg) {
   console.log(svg);
}, 'text');
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, except using the URL `/my.svg` just produces the path `file:///my.svg`, which obviously is not the location of the file.

Comment: can you find the source file `my.svg` in google chromes Inspect sources?

Comment: Yes, It does appear in sources.