# How to extract SVG element from external SVG file and append to HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286486/load-external-svg-file-into-variable-and-append-to-html) is similar, but the answer does not help.

The goal is to load an external SVG file (e.g., https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg), extract the SVG element, and append it to the HTML as an inline SVG element.

How can you do this?

We only want to use jQuery, no other third-party libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an svg element like this

```html
<svg id="mySvgElement" width="100" height="100"></svg>
```

then, you can get an external svg file and put its content into your svg element like this:

```
$.get(externalSvgUrl, function(response){
    var content = $(response).html();
    $("#mySvgElement").html(content);
});
```